# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes

Tags: drivers, freeze, radeon, amdgpu

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday, and it frequently freezes, Everything just stops, but I can move my mouse cursor (Can't click anything though).
The only thing I can do is a hard reboot.

I don't know if it's the gpu drivers issue, I couldn't find the drivers for my GPU AMD Radeon HD 8750.
I'm pretty new to Linux and I could really use some help.

Comment: It doesn't :(. I've looked at that answer before posting here.

Comment: What are the hardware specs? How much RAM you have?

Comment: Intel i7-4790 @ 3.6Ghz, 16 gigs of RAM and GPU: AMD Radeon HD 8750. Anything else?

Comment: And I don't think amdgpu/amdgpu-pro drivers exist for my gpu since it's old, currently I'm just using Radeon. Also, I don't know if this is important but I first installed 20.04, it had the same freezing issue where I can move my cursor but not click anything, I assumed something went wrong with the installation, I removed it and installed 18.04 instead, it's still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar issue a week ago, browsed many linux forums and turns out it was due to **Unstable Graphic Drivers**.

#### Backstory

---

I had Nouveau drivers installed, I tried to update to the latest drivers using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` followed by a reboot. I was able to login successfully but couldn't click anything on the desktop but my pointer was moving, hard rebooting was the only way out.

#### What can be done

---

1. On the login screen, type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get a TTY. Login using your name and password.
2. Remove your graphic drivers using `sudo amdgpu-pro-uninstall`(In my case it was NVIDIA `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`).
3. Type in the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon` followed by
4. `sudo apt install xserver-xorg`
5. `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`
6. Reboot the system to apply the changes using `sudo reboot`.

---

- Update to a stable/recommended driver but not to the latest driver available if you do not know the consequences. I reinstalled my OS 4 times in the last 12 months, It was an Nvidia driver issue 3 out of 4 times.

Comment: Apparently it's due to over queueing of frames, and setting the environment variable _GL_MaxFramesAllowes=1 solves the issue, it hasn't frozen yet after I did this, I'm not sure why or how it works though or if there's another fix.

Comment: Okay Update, it did not help, I'll try this and get back to you, surprisingly I don't even have AMD drivers installed I think, amdgpu-pro-uninstall gives a no command error

Comment: Didn't help, I reinstalled xserver-xorg-video-radeon, I didn't remove the amdgpu-pro drivers because apparently I didn't have any. It still froze